# JQuery Chosen Custom Component When Not Found Data

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I want to create custom component on jquery chosen select (by : https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), when there is no result.

So chosen select gives us a feature to create custom text on "no result", like this:

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"});
```

But, what I want is, when there is no result, I want some component like `button` or `a` inside "no-result-text", so that the user can interact with it. For instance, when there is no result, the user can click on a button, which shows a modal, or something.

Comment: Have you tried just changing the text to HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's not specified in the details, Chosen allows for HTML use in `no_results_text`, like so:

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({no_results_text: "<button>Add a new record!</button>"});
```

Comment: I don't know that it's allow to use HTML inside chosen.. haha.. it's work. thanks

Comment: Click the grey checkmark next to the answer and turn it green. Take a look at [this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if you're still unsure.